# how to set proxy in casperjs code

Tags: javascript, proxy, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Here are some options i already try but none of them work for me

 
is there any way to change proxy before we hit any particular website ?

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
setProxy: "proxy here",
// --proxy: "proxy here",
webSecurityEnabled: false,
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug",
waitTimeout: 100000,
pageSettings: {
    userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
    proxy: 'proxy here'
}});
var url = 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'ip_check.txt';
casper.start(url, function() {
    casper.cli.options["proxy"] = "proxy here";
    var js = this.evaluate(function() {
        return document; 
    }); 
    fs.write(path,js.all[0].outerHTML,'w'); 
});
casper.run();
```

Comment: You can't set proxy settings from inside of the CasperJS script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a proxy argument like this

`casperjs --proxy="switchproxy.proxify.net:7498" xyz.js`

Comment: This is not working for me. Getting timeout error. Any particular reason? I am using a HTTP proxy in the value